# Inserting rows from one table to other jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have two tables; both having a structure like one below:

```
<table id="someID">  
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <span> </span>
                </div>
            <td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have to insert all the columns of the second table after the first row of the first table. I have list of all the rows of the second element by `$("#someID > tbody > tr")` as jQuery object and get the first row of the table using `$("#someID tr:first")`. But how to combine these two components is something I am unable to figure out.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Typo: You forgot a `</div>`

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery's after function?

Comment: `$("#first > tbody > tr").insertAfter( $('#second tr:first') )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I have to insert all the columns of the **second table** after the first row of the **first table**"*

Use  `.after()` ***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/kapax/2/edit)***

```
$("#firstID tr:first").after( $('#secondID tr') );
```

or: `.insertAfter()` ***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/kapax/1/edit)***

```
$('#secondID tr').insertAfter( $("#firstID tr:first") );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table2 > tbody > tr").insertAfter($("#table1 tr:first"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Table 1</td>
      <td>Table 1</td>
      <td>Table 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Table 1</td>
      <td>Table 1</td>
      <td>Table 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<br/>
<table id="table2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Table 2</td>
      <td>Table 2</td>
      <td>Table 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Table 2</td>
      <td>Table 2</td>
      <td>Table 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```